# How to handle Relative Paths in jQuery and MVC, e.g. DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, relative-path, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an MVC3 application,
I know that for relative paths, I can use Url.Content in my .aspx Views.

However, how do I do something similar in jQuery? The one I'm looking at is the jquery-ui datepicker, e.g. I have the following EditorTemplate for my datetimem DateTime.ascx:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime>" %> 
    <%: Html.TextBox("", this.Model.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { @class="datepicker"}) %> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', 
            gotoCurrent: true, 
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: '../../../Content/images/calendar.png'  // WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
        });

    });   
    </script>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think this is not the answer?

`<%= Url.Content("/Content/images/calendar.png") %>`

Comment: I didn't think it would work (but I tested, and it does!) e.g. buttonImage: '<%= Url.Content("~/Content/images/calendar.png") %>'... Isn't Url.Content MVC specific? So if I wanted to re-use this library in a non MVC application, I would be in trouble, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
   gotoCurrent: true,
   showOn: 'button',
   buttonImageOnly: true,
   buttonImage: '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/calendar.png")'
 });
});   
</script>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the other post on just using '<%= Url.Content("blah") %>' was okay.

Comment: I used razor in my answer. New MVC3 projects use razor by default so when I read MVC3 I thought it was razor.

Comment: This one works for me in MVC5 - and I thought it should work in MVC3 as well.